# How can DELETE requests be made with a Dart HttpClient?

Tags: dart, dart-io

If you're using a Dart `HttpClient` (which provides an `HttpClientRequest`) to make requests from a server to another server, as far as I can tell the only HTTP methods available are `GET` and `POST` (corresponding, respectively, to the `post`/`postUrl` and `get`/`getUrl` functions). Is there also a way to make `PUT` and `DELETE` requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do with this with the [open](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/dev/#dart-io.HttpClient@id_open) method which allows you to use any HTTP verb:

```dart
client.open('delete', 'http://example.com', '8080', '/test');
```

If you look at the [HttpClient source](https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/sdk/lib/io/http_impl.dart) you'll see that the `get` and `post` methods are just aliases for `open` anyway:

```dart
Future<HttpClientRequest> post(String host,
                                 int port,
                                 String path) {
    return open("post", host, port, path);
}
```

Comment: what if you wanna pass in parameters to delete function?