# how do i do a delete request from api? - flutter

Tags: json, flutter, http-delete

I know how to do get and post request but im unsure on how to do delete request?

my json url and it's requirements:

```
String url = "http://35.186.145.243:8080/users";

{
"userId":"user1",
"price":"$1.300"
}
```

so i need to pass userId and price as parameters in order to delete the information from the api

```
  main() async {
    String url = "http://35.186.145.243:8080";

    Map map = {
      'user_id': "user1",
      'price': "$1.300",
    };

    print(await apiRequest(url, map));
  }

  Future<String> apiRequest(String url, Map jsonMap) async {
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.open('delete', url, 0, '/users');
    httpClient.close();
    return 'Success';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("API DELETE"),
      ),
      body:
          Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              child: Text("DELETE!"),
              onPressed: () => main(),
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Try the following [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460194/how-can-delete-requests-be-made-with-a-dart-httpclient), if you have a problem don't forget to mension the problem, I cant really get the problem your facing from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing port number from your URL and adding it to the port parameter in http open method.

`String url = "http://35.186.145.243";`

`httpClient.open('delete', url, 8080, '/users');`